# Best way in python to check if a loop is not executed

Tags: python, return

The title might be misleading, so here is a better explanation.

Consider the following code:

```py
def minimum_working_environment(r):
    trial=np.arange(0,6)[::-1]
    for i in range(len(trial)):
        if r>trial[i]:
            return i
    return len(trial)
```

We see that if `r` is smaller than the smallest element of `trial`, the `if` clause inside the loop is never executed. Therefore, the function never returns anything in the loop and returns something in the last line. If the `if` clause inside the loop is executed, `return` terminates the code, so the last line is never executed.

I want to implement something similar, but without return, i.e.,

```py
def minimum_working_environment(self,r):
    self.trial=np.arange(0,6)[::-1]
    for i in range(len(self.trial)):
        if r>trial[i]:
            self.some_aspect=i
            break
    self.some_aspect=len(self.trial)
```

Here, `break` disrupts the loop but the function is not terminated.

The solutions I can think of are:

- Replace `break` with `return 0` and not check the return value of the function.
- Use a flag variable.
- Expand the `self.trial` array with a very small negative number, like `-1e99`.

First method looks good, I will probably implement it if I don't get any answer. The second one is very boring. The third one is not just boring but also might cause performance problems.

My questions are:

Is there a reserved word like `return` that would work in the way that I want, i.e., terminate the function?

If not, what is the best solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Why not just use the return like you already do??

Comment: Just replace the `break` with `return`. The last line of the function is already followed by an implicit `return`.

Comment: @luk2302 I want to change an object variable so I don't need a return. If possible, I want to do this without return.

Comment: @quamrana I thought of that. It is my first solution proposal. I just wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: You know that you can just `return` without returning a value??

Comment: @luk2302 I didn't. I could still return 0, but wanted to check if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that a `for` loop did not run into a `break` with `else`, which seems to be what you're after.

```
import numpy as np


def minimum_working_environment(r):
    trial = np.arange(0, 6)[::-1]
    for i in range(len(trial)):
        if r > trial[i]:
            return i
    return len(trial)


def alternative(r):
    trial = np.arange(0, 6)[::-1]
    for i in range(len(trial)):
        if r > trial[i]:
            break
    else:
        i = len(trial)
    return i


print(minimum_working_environment(3))
print(minimum_working_environment(-3))

print(alternative(3))
print(alternative(-3))
```

Result:

```
3
6
3
6
```

This works because the loop controlling variable `i` will still have the last value it had in the loop after the `break` and the `else` will only be executed if the `break` never executes.

However, if you just want to terminate a function, you should use `return`. The example I provided is mainly useful if you do indeed need to know if a loop completed fully (i.e. without breaking) or if it terminated early. It works for your example, which I assume was exactly that, just an example.